# Selecting a range of rows using 3 different indices

Tags: sql, mysql

My database looks like this:

```
Book,Chapter,Verse,Scripture
"1","1","1","1text1"
"1","1","2","1text2"
"1","1","3","1text3"
"1","1","4","1text4"
"1","2","1","2text1"
"1","2","2","2text2"
"1","2","3","2text3"
```

I want to select all the rows from 1,1,1 to 1,2,3.

However my current query will not return row 1,1,4 because 4 is greater than 3.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 
Book >= 1 AND Book <= 1 AND 
Chapter >= 1 AND Chapter <= 2 AND
Verse >= 1 AND Verse <= 3
```

Comment: I think there's something missing.  Why not just omit the chapter and verse criteria since it seems like you want everything from book 1?

Comment: Can you specify your requirements a little more?  What data do you want to exclude with your query?

Comment: The table has 66 books, each book having up to 100 or more chapters and each chapter having up to 100 or more verses.

I want to be able to select 1,1,1 through 1,5,5 or 2,4,3 through 3,1,1.

Comment: @Daniel: It's unrealistic to write a single SQL query to handle all your filter criteria at any given time.  See my answer for examples.

Comment: @rexem: So if I want 1,1,$x through 2,5,$y would I need to join three different select statements?
1st query to handle verses in the first chapter greater than $x.
2nd query to handle all verses between the first and last chapters.
3rd query to handle verses in last chapter less than $y.

Comment: @Daniel: No, you need set your WHERE clause according to what you want to get back.  You've shown to be using numerically ordered data; you only need to use UNIONs if you have mutually exclusive datasets, which you don't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL also supports [row constructors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/row-subqueries.html). If you wanted (e.g.) 1 1:3 through 1 2:2, use:

```
SELECT * FROM bible
    WHERE (1,1,3) <= (book, chapter, verse) AND (book, chapter, verse) <= (1,2,2)
```

For 58 1:3 to 62 4:2,

```
SELECT * FROM bible
    WHERE (58,1,3) <= (book, chapter, verse) AND (book, chapter, verse) <= (62,4,2)
```

58 1:4 will be included, as will 59 1:1 and 60 10:10, but not 62 5:1.

I can't find much documentation, but MySQL follows the behavior set down for row comparisons since [SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) (note: the link is to a draft version), specifically Section 8.2 "General Rules" 7):

> Let R<sup>x</sup> and R<sup>y</sup> be the two row value constructors of the comparison predicate and let R<sup>x</sup><sub>i</sub> and R<sup>y</sup><sub>i</sub> be the i-th row value constructor elements of R<sup>x</sup> and R<sup>y</sup>, respectively. "R<sup>x</sup> [comp op] R<sup>y</sup>" is true, false, or unknown as follows:
>   [...]
>   c) "R<sup>x</sup> < R<sup>y</sup>" is true if and only if R<sup>x</sup><sub>i</sub> = R<sup>y</sup><sub>i</sub> for all i < n and R<sup>x</sup><sub>n</sub> < R<sup>y</sup><sub>n</sub> for some n.
>
> d) "R<sup>x</sup> > R<sup>y</sup>" is true if and only if R<sup>x</sup><sub>i</sub> = R<sup>y</sup><sub>i</sub> for all i < n and R<sup>x</sup><sub>n</sub> > R<sup>y</sup><sub>n</sub> for some n.
>
> e) "R<sup>x</sup> <= R<sup>y</sup>" is true if and only if R<sup>x</sup> = R<sup>y</sup> or R<sup>x</sup> < R<sup>y</sup>.
>
> f) "R<sup>x</sup> >= R<sup>y</sup>" is true if and only if R<sup>x</sup> = R<sup>y</sup> or R<sup>x</sup> > R<sup>y</sup>.

Row comparisons are covered in section 9.2 Joe Celko's [SQL For Smarties](http://books.google.com/books?id=Hi9fMnOoRtAC&pg=PA238&lpg=PA238&dq=%22Row+Comparisons+in+SQL%22&source=bl&ots=ts9O_hVaYp&sig=Ge5yoE6Swv4N9RpKJUeE0kLm498&hl=en&ei=xzueSvz6DoOIswOxqYUa&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#v=onepage&q=%22Row%20Comparisons%20in%20SQL%22&f=false) (link is to 3rd Ed., but the same topic existed in earlier editions).

Comment: This does look hopeful, unfortunately the manual page is so vague it's impossible to determine if this is is actually the feature Daniel needs.

Answer (score 1):

What's missing from your data model is the fact that Book, Chapter, and verse are hierarchically related.

If for each entry, you also stored single data item that combined book chapter and verse together,  searching for a given range would involve just a simple BETWEEN operator.

Let's say that you knew that no book contains more than 99 chapters, and no chapter contains more than 999 verses.  You could compute (Book*100+Chapter)*1000+Verse
for each item stored, and store that in a separate column.  (Yes, I know this is redundant).

Then you could search for that column between  (1*100 + 1)*1000 + 1 and (1*100+2)*1000+5
to find everything from 1,1,1 to 1,2,5.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an OR statement.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 
(Book = 1 AND 
Chapter BETWEEN 1 AND 2
Verse BETWEEN 1 AND 2)
OR
(/* THE OTHER STATEMENT */)
OR
(/* THE OTHER STATEMENT */)
```

### Edit

And is much more clear if you use the [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/comparison-operators.html) operator

Comment: I don't know how many verses are in a chapter unless I check. For example, I want to select all the verses in chapter 1 but in chapter 2 I only want to select up to verse 5.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with for selecting a range within a book.
If I want from 1,1,3 to 1,7,2

```
SELECT * FROM Bible WHERE Book = 1 AND Chapter = 1 AND Verse >= 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM Bible WHERE Book = 1 AND Chapter >1 AND Chapter <7
UNION
SELECT * FROM Bible WHERE Book = 1 AND Chapter = 7 AND Verse <=2
```

To select a range across books: 58,1,3 to 62,4,2

```
SELECT * FROM Bible WHERE Book = 58 AND Chapter = 1 AND Verse >= 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM Bible WHERE Book = 58 AND Chapter > 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Bible WHERE Book > 58 AND Book < 62
UNION
SELECT * FROM Bible WHERE Book = 62 AND Chapter < 4
UNION
SELECT * FROM Bible WHERE Book = 62 AND Chapter = 4 AND Verse <=2
```

Comment: ::sigh:: If you're going to use UNIONs, use UNION ALL because duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of involves adding an additional column for indexing:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD VerseIndex CHAR(10) NOT NULL, INDEX(VerseIndex(4));

UPDATE my_table SET VerseIndex = CONCAT(
                                        LPAD(Book, 2, '0'),
                                        '-', LPAD(Chapter, 3, '0'),
                                        '-', LPAD(Verse, 3, '0')
                                        );
```

You should now have an extra column in your table with a text value of '--', which mysql can search alphabetically to give you an exact range:

```
# find book 2 chapter 4 v 3 through to book 3 chapter 1 v 1 (inclusive)
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE VerseIndex BETWEEN '02-004-003' AND '03-001-001' ORDER BY VerseIndex;

# find book 5 chapter 4 (whole chapter) through to book 7 end of chapter 9
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE VerseIndex BETWEEN '05-004-000' AND '07-009-999' ORDER BY VerseIndex;
```